# Filling expansion joints before self-leveling concrete?

Tags: concrete, self-leveling-concrete

I am adding self-leveling concrete to my basement flooring. I have expansion joints which are currently filled with a joint compound. How would I fill in the expansion joints so that I can cover the flooring with the self-leveling concrete mix?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clean out any debris from the expansion gaps. Then you need to fill the expansion gaps with a flexible filler like “DAP  Flexible floor patch and leveler“. That will ensure your expansion gaps continue to function and not fill with leveling compound.

Comment: If the cracks are deep, you may want to stuff "backer rod" into them first to partly fill them, then use filler over the backer rod. Faster and easier than trying to fill a large space with just the leveling compound.